# RDBMS: How to represent a composite entity

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I have an entity, for example `compound_tax`. Each `compound_tax` could be composed of several instances of another entity `tax`. For example, one `compound_tax` could be composed of two taxes (order could be important):

```
VAT:         4.5% of Net Total (tax)
Service Tax: 3.4% of Net Total (tax)
------------------------------------
Total Tax:   7.9% of Net Total  (compound_tax)
```

What is the best way to create these tables? Is there a standard practice?

Here's the solution I have in mind, though I'm not sure if that's the right solution. Please let me hear pros and cons, if possible:

```
Table: taxes {PK: tax_id}
+--------+-------------+------+------------+
| tax_id | tax_name    | rate | tax_type   |
+--------+-------------+------+------------+
| 1      | VAT         | 4.5  | single     |
+--------+-------------+------+------------+
| 2      | Service Tax | 3.4  | single     |
+--------+-------------+------+------------+
| 3      | Total Tax   | 7.9  | compound   |
+--------+-------------+------+------------+

Table: compound_taxes {PK: (ctax_id, tax_id), FK(tax_id)}
+--------+-------------+--------+
| ctax_id | tax_id     | order  |
+---------+------------+--------+
| 3       | 1          | 1      |
+-------- +------------+--------+
| 3       | 2          | 2      |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

**UPDATE:**
Answers to @Егор Рогов's questions:

- Can the same "single tax" belongs to several different compound taxes?" - Yes.
- Is there a chance that some compound taxes can be composed of another compound taxes? - Yes.
- What queries are you going to perform over that tables?" - I need a quick list all taxes with rates, essentially a SELECT on taxes. I would need to be able to UPDATE taxes, including compound taxes, which would involve INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE on `compound_taxes` as well as `taxes`.
- Do you want to calculate total rate for compound taxes or have it "hardcoded" into the table?" - I'm ok with either. I hardcoded it because in that way I run a simple `SELECT` on `taxes` to get a list of all taxes along with the rates.

Comment: Some questions that can help to make a decision. Can the same "single tax" belongs to several different compound taxes? Is there a chance that some compound taxes can be composed of another compound taxes? What queries are you going to perform over that tables? Do you want to calculate total rate for compound taxes or have it "hardcoded" into the table (like it is now)?

Comment: "Can the same "single tax" belongs to several different compound taxes?" - Yes. "Is there a chance that some compound taxes can be composed of another compound taxes?" - Yes. "What queries are you going to perform over that tables?" - I need a quick list all taxes with rates, essentially a SELECT on `taxes`. I would need to be able to UPDATE taxes, including compound taxes, which would involve INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE on `compound_taxes` as well as `taxes`. "Do you want to calculate total rate for compound taxes or have it "hardcoded" into the table?" - I'm ok with either.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the other way round. You should have a foreign key (compound_tax_id) on taxes table (its name should be tax, not taxes indeed) pointing to compound tax, so you could have several taxes pointing to the same compound tax. You would have 'order' field in this tabl as well.

The other table should be called compound_tax. And it would only have one field (id). To know the taxes belonging to a compound_tax you would perform a SELECT query on tax table by compound_tax_id

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, each instance of compound tax is composed of some permutation of taxes. If you are using PostgreSQL, declare compound tax field as Array type. That will also take care of your "position " requirement. 
If not, then use a comma-separated string type for compound tax and convert to array programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the design you have is OK and that will fulfill your requirements.
But that have some problems needs to be high lighted.

1. In `compound_taxes` table nothing is going to prevent a single tax
   record being inserted as `ctax_id`. like:

   ```
        +--------+-------------+--------+
        | ctax_id | tax_id     | order  |
        +---------+------------+--------+
        | 1       | 2          | 1      |
        +-------- +------------+--------+
   ```
2. An update on `tax_type` column of `taxes` table can make data
   inconsistency.

I suggest having other design:
Having a parent table called `Tax` for all kind of tax elements(single and compound). This Tax table will have zero-or-one relation to all of tax types. A record in Tax table will show one and only one record in one of other tables.

Consider Tax as an abstract entity that will contain shared properties of all tax types. Single and compound will inherit from Tax.
[image]